# How to convert closure to js_sys::Function?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

How to convert a local closure into a [`js_sys::Function`](https://docs.rs/js-sys/latest/js_sys/struct.Function.html)?

I want to do something like this:

```rust
let canvas = document.get_element_by_id("canvas").unwrap();
let e: web_sys::HtmlElement = canvas.dyn_into().unwrap();
let f = || {};
e.set_onresize(Some(&f.into()));
```

Answer (score 9):

I have found a solution [here](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/passing-rust-closures-to-js.html):

```
let f = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || { /* whatever */}) as Box<dyn FnMut()>);
e.set_onresize(Some(f.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
f.forget(); // It is not good practice, just for simplification!
```

Comment: Any idea how a function with arguments can be converted to js_sys::Function as well?

Comment: @ChetanBhasin, the same way (I guess!), what error do you get?

Comment: Is there a reason why it isn't possible to use `dyn_into` to convert the `Closure` into a `js_sys::Function`?

Comment: @mallwright the answer is outdated, I think the whole process has been changed.

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour do you have a link to a blog or some examples? As far as I can tell there have only been a few changes around the ergonomics of the APIs since 2020.

Answer (score 0):

An answer can be found on the [`wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen/latest/wasm_bindgen/closure/struct.Closure.html#casting-a-closure-to-a-js_sysfunction) page, as well.

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::{closure::Closure, JsCast};

let cb = Closure::new(|| { ... });
let cb = cb.as_ref().unchecked_ref();
```

Comment: I got this to compile after a cast: `cb : Closure<dyn FnMut()>`. But when used as a callback to an HtmlInputElement, the browser logged an error: "closure invoked recursively or after being dropped"

Comment: Could it be because a variable needed to be `move`d into the `Closure`, but wasn't?

Comment: No, I don't think that's it. You need to call `forget()` to avoid the error: `let cb: Closure<dyn FnMut()> = Closure::new(move || {...}); file_picker.set_oninput(Some(cb.as_ref().unchecked_ref())); cb.forget();`

Answer (score 0):

The following way to set a closure as a callback is slightly shorter than shown in [Hossein Noroozpour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054963/how-to-convert-closure-to-js-sysfunction#60058227). It's adapted from this [example](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/843#issuecomment-422095718):

```
let closure: Closure<dyn Fn()> = Closure::new(move || {
      // Do something here
});
your_html_element.set_oninput(Some(closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
closure.forget();
```

---

Here's a more complete example, showing how to set the callback on a [file picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file). The callback accesses a JavaScript [worker](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/examples/wasm-in-web-worker.html):

```
let document = window().unwrap().document().unwrap();
let worker = Worker::new("./worker.js").unwrap();

let file_picker_elem_id = "file_picker";
match get_input_element(file_picker_elem_id, &document) {
    Some(file_picker) => {
        // We need "move" to access the worker inside the closure
        let closure: Closure<dyn Fn()> = Closure::new(move || {
            log_to_browser(format!(
                "The file picker callback. Worker: {worker:?}"
            ));
        });
        file_picker.set_oninput(Some(closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
        closure.forget();
    }
    None => log_to_browser(format!(
        "Couldn't get file picker. Used \"{file_picker_elem_id}\" as its ID"
    )),
}

/// Gets an [[HtmlInputElement]] by its `elem_id`.
fn get_input_element(elem_id: &str, document: &Document) -> Option<HtmlInputElement> {
    document
        .get_element_by_id(elem_id)
        .and_then(|elem| elem.dyn_ref::<HtmlInputElement>().map(ToOwned::to_owned))
}
fn log_to_browser(log_msg: String) {
    console::log_1(&log_msg.into());
}
```

---

I tried simplifying the conversion of closures to `js_sys::Function`s:

```
pub fn to_js_func<F>(closure: F) -> Option<&'static js_sys::Function>
where
    F: IntoWasmClosure<dyn Fn()> + 'static,
{
    let big_closure: Closure<dyn Fn()> = Closure::new(closure);

    let func: &js_sys::Function = big_closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref();
    big_closure.forget();
    Some(func)
}
```

But this doesn't work since the function owns the created closure. Also, to use the type `js_sys::Function`, I needed to add the `js-sys` dependency to Cargo.toml. If anybody knows a way around this, please let us know.

---

A less universal helper function that works though:

```
fn set_on_input<F>(input_elem: &HtmlInputElement, closure: F)
where
    F: IntoWasmClosure<dyn Fn()> + 'static,
{
    let big_closure: Closure<dyn Fn()> = Closure::new(closure);
    input_elem.set_oninput(Some(big_closure.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    big_closure.forget();
}
```

This allows setting a Rust closure as the callback on the HTML element:

```
let closure = move || {
    log_to_browser(format!(
        "The file picker callback. Worker: {worker:?}"
    ));
};
set_on_input(&file_picker, closure);
```

Instead of a closure, you can also set a function as the callback:

```
set_on_input(&file_picker, test_callback);
```

Where `test_callback` is just a regular Rust function:

```
fn test_callback() {
    log_to_browser("test_callback ".into());
}
```