# web-sys define js_sys::Function

Tags: rust, web-sys

How do I define a [`js_sys::Function`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/struct.Function.html#) that must be used in [`get_current_position`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.Geolocation.html#method.get_current_position) to get the users latitude and longitude coordinates?

I have the following

```rust
let navigator = web_sys::window().expect("Missing window").navigator();
let geolocation = navigator.geolocation().unwrap();

geolocation.get_current_position(|pos: JsValue| {
    // logic omitted for brevity
})
```

which gives the following compile error by `wasm-pack build --target web`:

```
    |       geolocation.get_current_position(|pos: JsValue| {
    |  ______________________________________^
    | |
    | |     });
    | |_____^ expected `&Function`, found closure
```

As I understand, the argument needs to be a [`js_sys::Function`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/struct.Function.html#) instead of an ordinary rust closure. The [documentation](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/struct.Function.html#) is a bit vague, but I think I need to use `new_with_args` ?

Comment: [Passing Rust Closures to Imported JavaScript Functions](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/passing-rust-closures-to-js.html)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for the link. However, I am still confused how I can practically apply it. Say I wanted to create a *Stack-lifetime closure*, how do I pass it as an argument to ```geolocation.get_current_position``` ?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60054963/how-to-convert-closure-to-js-sysfunction).